# Specific Algorithm that shapely.geometry.Polygon.area uses

Tags: python, math, area, shapely

Can anyone point me to any documentation/source code that refers to which algorithm `shapely.area` uses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's open source, is "just going to the code repository and reading the files" somehow not working for you?

Comment: in theory I agree with @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment... but in reality it is not always as easy as one might think... shapely wraps [GEOS](https://libgeos.org/) and all you can find in the shapely code is `lib.area(...)` where `lib` points to pre-compiled `pyd` file... so you'd need to dig into [GEOS](https://libgeos.org/) to find the actual lines of code that do the job (written in C or C++)

Comment: Which is fine, but then that [should be mentioned in the post](/help/how-to-ask) as reason for asking =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, shapely is just a wrapper for GEOS, so I guess what you're looking for is this:

https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/main/src/algorithm/Area.cpp

And the used algorithm seems to be the [Shoelace Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).